# Group Admins Mystery - RHEL 7

Tags: rhel

Plese check the following one :

```
[root@servertest /]# groupadd admins
groupadd: group 'admins' already exists

[root@servertest /]# grep -q -E "^admins:" /etc/group
[root@servertest /]#

[root@servertest ~]# usermod -aG admins user1
[root@servertest ~]# groups user1
user1 : user1

[root@servertest Packages]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

Groups "admins" seems to exist , but its somehow invisible.
  Can anyone explain this behaviour ?

Comment: man grep says: `-q` Quiet;  do not write anything to standard output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system might be connected to AD, LDAP or NIS and get some extra non-local users and/or groups from there. "usermod" might not be the right tool for managing those users or groups.

What does `grep -e '^group' -e '^passwd' /etc/nsswitch.conf` say?

If it mentions `sssd`, `winbind`, `ldap` or `nis`, then the local `/etc/group` might not tell the full story.

Comment: Correct, this machine is indeed connected to LDAP!  nsswitch.conf  contains sssd keyword in passwd as well in group entries. Thanks a lot telcoM!

Comment: That's it then: the `admins` group is in LDAP and you probably don't have permission to add users to it, even if you are root locally.